# App Store Taxable Sales, US

Tags: united-states, new-york, sales-tax

Trying to determine "Taxable Sales" for App Store sales for Sales Tax filing purposes.

As everyone knows Apple or Google take a 30% cut of all the sales, so my question is do "Taxable Sales" count from 100% of the sale or only from the 70% that I get to keep?

For example an app sells for $1.00

Apple / Google take $0.30

I keep $0.70

Are my taxable sales $1.00 or $0.70 ?

Comment: Can you add a country tag. Also are you looking a sales tax or income tax? How are you selling this? As individual or some company/partnership? What is the approx turnover or money from such sales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to figure this out myself. As per definition "Taxable Sale" is the whole amount of $1 since the buyer will pay sales tax on that whole $1.

The $0.70 is your profit and has nothing to do with "Taxable Sale" - its just your take of what you get to keep.

An interesting side point to make is that when you file you personal tax return (not sales tax return) you still need to list the $1 as your revenue and $0.30 as expense listed as fees.

Comment: Essentially it's no different than a bricks-and-mortar shop selling something for $1 where 30 cents of that goes towards the sales assistant's salary.